# How can I move an item with a specific property to the top of a PHP array

Tags: php

I have an associative array that looks like so:

```
   {
      "album_6":{
        "name":"02-04-2014",
        "id":6,
        "count":"2",
        "cover":"26974771533c4b57cb0aa"
      },
      "album_3":{
        "name":"Photos of you",
        "id":3,
        "count":"4",
        "cover":"8872935615302242c4fa6c",
        "of_you":true
      }
    }
```

Thy array can contain many items but one of the items will have the extra property `of_you`.

In the above example it is `album_3`

I would like to move the item that has the `of_you` property to the first position in the array.  How can I achieve this?

I have tried using `usort` with a comparison function but it doesn't seem to work.

Note:  The item could be at any numerical index.

**ANSWER:**

I found the answer literally straight after posting this question.  The solution is as follows:

```
  uasort($albums, function($a, $b) {
      return (empty($a['of_you'])) ? 1 : -1;
  });
```

If anyone has a faster/more efficient method.  Please post it as an answer and I will accept.

**EDIT:** in order to mantain the associative keys `asort()` is a better choice in this instance

Comment: Show the code you tried

Comment: You don't need asort, as you are sorting array of arrays, so the keys on the sorted array are numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it didn't work for you, `usort` is the way:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $hasA = array_key_exists('of_you', $a);
    $hasB = array_key_exists('of_you', $b);

    if ($hasA and $hasB) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $hasA ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Keep in mind, it will not do more sort than first the elements with the key of_you and then the rest.

Comment: Thanks.  would this be more or less efficient that the comparison function that I wrote?

Comment: Well, personally don't like using empty regularly. Empty means: does it exist, if yes, does it have a value which is not null, "", 0, etc. In your case you only have to say whether it exists or not. Also, by returning 0 if both element has the key, then it won't move it anywhere. So I would say it is a bit more efficient.